# Web scraping with Excel VBA to get hotel details

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape [www.booking.com](http://www.booking.com) to get some hotel information based on a search i did on the website. The url is containing my search like address, check-in etc.

After the search, i am trying to scrape the hotel name, score, distance and other information without going further into detail (by clicking on the hotel). But in some way i cant go through the steps to get this information.

If i am right, all the search results are placed in the ID "hotellist_inner", which contains all the seperate hotel results in class "sr_property_block". But i already get an error on the first line:
For Each itemEle In objIE.Document.getElementsById("hotellist_inner"), as it seems that the result of getElementById is empty.

See my example code below.

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("scrape")
Dim objIE As Object
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


Dim url As String
url = ws.Range("A1")

With objIE
    .navigate url
    .Visible = True
End With

'wait IE
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

ResRw = 2

For Each itemEle In objIE.Document.getElementById("hotellist_inner")
     'Every booking goes on a new line, so reset the column to 1
    ResCol = 1
    For Each d In itemEle.getElementByClassName("sr_property_block ") 'Each result (hotel) has this Class
                                 
         'For the next result, add 1 to the column
         ResCol = ResCol + 1
    Next d
    
    'For the next result, add 1 to the row
    ResRw = ResRw + 1
Next

objIE.Quit
Set objIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Sample url: https://www.booking.com/searchresults.nl.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaKkBiAEBmAEcuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AEDiAIBqAIDuAL-25KJBsACAdICJDQ5MDk4ZmU4LWE3MDYtNGEwNi1hZTY2LWYzYTc5YmQwZWU2M9gCBOACAQ&sid=c7a70093e9732a158e970a642f2af63f&sb=1&sb_lp=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.nl.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaKkBiAEBmAEcuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AEDiAIBqAIDuAL-25KJBsACAdICJDQ5MDk4ZmU4LWE3MDYtNGEwNi1hZTY2LWYzYTc5YmQwZWU2M9gCBOACAQ%3Bsid%3Dc7a70093e9732a158e970a642f2af63f%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss=Amsterdam%2C+Noord-Holland%2C+Nederland&is_ski_area=&checkin_year=2021&checkin_month=8&checkin_monthday=24&checkout_year=2021&checkout_month=8&checkout_monthday=31&group_adults=1&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1&ss_raw=Amsterdam&ac_position=0&ac_langcode=nl&ac_click_type=b&dest_id=-2140479&dest_type=city&iata=AMS&place_id_lat=52.372898&place_id_lon=4.893&search_pageview_id=694a3bbf21c20007&search_selected=true&search_pageview_id=694a3bbf21c20007&ac_suggestion_list_length=5&ac_suggestion_theme_list_length=0

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Tnx!

Comment: Please provide some sample URL

Comment: Is anything happening?  any errors?